# How To Show Mark up Point on map in Android and show shortest distance Between 1st point to current point with polilines .?

Tags: android

```
                map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
                stop = map.addMarker(new
                 MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                 .title("Stop"));
                //Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(KIEL, 15));

                // Zoom in, animating the camera.
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000,
                        null);
```

Now I am Using Code For show map and on Show marker Which is Mention above with using `google api` key but not getting result for show shortest distance with polyline .
Can You Please Help me .??

Comment: please explain more on this. what u want?

Comment: I Want To Show Shortest Path On Map Between To point in android .

Comment: r u used DrivingDirection?

Comment: then as per my way u can get distance like `float[] results = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(
      point1_pos.latitude,
      point1_pos.latitude,
      cur_pos.latitude, cur_pos.longitude, results);
    System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]);` then store this distance into `arrayList.add((int) results[0]);` and then find minimum index from that like `int minIndex = arrayList
     .indexOf(Collections.min(arrayList));` and load  it

Comment: But How to Show On Map With Poly Lines On Road .?

Comment: that's very easy. now as per my above solution u can get minimum distance points then add like 
 `Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(minimum point position, current position)
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));`

Comment: But Its Show Straight Line and i want to show Path in Road Wise .